# Spring Boot - Pre-bound JDBC Connection found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I am implementing a Spring boot Web service application and trying to connect it with MySQL database, which is also connected by Laravel (PHP) Application. Following exception is occuring on beginning the transaction:

> org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException:
>   Pre-bound JDBC Connection found! JpaTransactionManager does not
>   support running within DataSourceTransactionManager if told to manage
>   the DataSource itself. It is recommended to use a single
>   JpaTransactionManager for all transactions on a single DataSource, no
>   matter whether JPA or JDBC access.    at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:359)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
>   ~[spring-tx-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]  at
>   com.azampay.core.services.BaseService.startTransaction(BaseService.java:45)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   com.azampay.core.services.DelegateServiceImpl.getDelegates(DelegateServiceImpl.java:225)
>   ~[classes/:na]

**Application.java**
In application.java, I am providing my own TransactionManager:

```
@Bean   
@Primary    
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {

        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return jpaTransactionManager;   
}
```

and for beginning the transaction:

```
DefaultTransactionDefinition defaultTransactionDefinition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
defaultTransactionDefinition.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
TransactionStatus status = platformTransactionManager.getTransaction(defaultTransactionDefinition);
```

**Solutions (I have tried)**

I have tried to exlude the DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class in Application.java. Similarly, I made my transactionmanager as a @Primary. But nothing works.

Can anyone help me to solve this? I have already search SO and google but could not find any solution.